# How do you select certain letters from a text document in an external file?

Tags: python

How do you select the first letters of certain words in an external file in Python? I need to print the song artist and the first letter of every word of the song title, but I don't know the code to do so.

```
login= "password"
password = input("please enter password:")
if password == login:
    print("password corect, welcome!")
else:
    print("incorrect, not allowed in")
file = open("song game.txt", "r")
import random
with open("song game.txt") as f:
    print(random.choice(f.readlines()))
def letters1(s):
    space = ""
    s = space + s
    temp = ""
    for k in range(len(s)):
        if s[k] == space:
            temp+= s[k+1]
    return temp
```

Comment: Which part of that specifically are you struggling with? Opening the file? Reading its content? Parsing the content? Initialising the appropriate parts?

Comment: what have you done?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. While we're all here glad to help, SO is not a free coding service. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: currently i have made code that prints the song name and artist as a whole not just the artist plus the first letters of the song name i just need the code to print just the artist plus first letter of every word in the song title so i can continue with the rest of my project

Comment: @Leeh show us what you've done so far to help you.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis added image link at the start

Comment: @Leeh i fixed your code so that's how you should ask next time.

Answer (score 2):

First of all add you code correctly to your question not as an image url.
Now let's say you have the following txt file:

**test.txt**

> This is a song and I will get the first letters of each word.

The following would be a simple and efficient solution for what you're trying to do:

```py
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read().split(' ')

print(''.join(word[0] for word in text))
```

Splitting the words on spaces and for every word getting the first character. Try not to think complicated. The above could even be done in a line:

```py
print(''.join(word[0] for word in open('test.txt', 'r').read().split(' ')))
```

Comment: thank you for help with the code, sorry about the vague question, new to SO

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a naming convention for song name and the song artist you can go with something like this:

This is based on a naming convention kind of: **Nice Artist-The Beautiful Song**

```
file_location = r'c:\yourfilelocation' #Your file location:

song_content = open(file_location,'r').read() # open is the method to open a file, and 'r' stands for read

song_artist = song_content.split('-')[0]

song_name = song_content.split('-')[1]

first_letters = []
for a in range(len(song_name.split())):
    separated_words = song_name.split(' ')[a]
    first_letter = separated_words[0]
    first_letters.append(first_letter)


print(first_letters)
```

Depends how dynamic you want it to be. This one could be a good start.

For more on file management with python check this:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open